# JBullet: How to add heightmap to dynamic world?

Tags: java, lwjgl, jbullet

I implements `JBullet` into my code. Boxes, spheres work prefectly. But I don't have idea how to implement to my world heightmap(as static object). What type of shape I must use and how?

My heightmap array was something like this `float[world_size][world_size]`.

Answer (score 1):

As it looks like JBullet does not include the heightmap shape you could propably use the [BvhTriangleMeshShape](http://jbullet.advel.cz/javadoc/com/bulletphysics/collision/shapes/BvhTriangleMeshShape.html) as I think it fits your needs best.